# ServiceStack SSE shut down IIS application pool

Tags: servicestack

My company has chat application built on ServiceStack SSE (v.4.5.14). Recently, we keep getting following exceptions which sometimes can make IIS application pool shut down.

```
System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
  at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
  at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
  at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
  at System.IO.Stream+<>c.<BeginWriteInternal>b__46_0 (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.IO.Stream.EndWrite (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.IO.Stream+<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_1 (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
```

After a quick research, we found [this article](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/sse-exceptions-while-publishing-notifications/4312) that explains the reason behind this issue. However, we are not quite sure about the solution. Should we also add this compesssion setting, mentioned in article:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
```

Or could anyone share how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Changes have been made to ServiceStack SSE in v5 so upgrading to the latest v5 may resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! We thought the fix is rolled out in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/2b60599f451021c2d8cab46614e55dc6cb55ed7c). Since we encapsulated ServiceStack configurations and shared across our team, we would like to update it as slow as possible. Hence, is it possible that you can show me which specific commit resolved this issue?

Comment: I don't of a specific commit just that a number of changes have been made since, you can compare against the latest version of [ServerEventsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs).

Comment: Ok, It looks like some features had been added into SSE after 4.5.14. We will update it for our app. Thank you so much for your helps!